# qml virtual keyboard: keyboardDesignWidth and Height

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am looking at the QML Style for the virtual keyboard. What is the purpose of keyboardDesignWidth and Height? I seem to have a lot of trouble managing the width and height of the keyboard and can never set it to how I want it. Setting the keyboardHeight and Width directly also does not help much.

The issue is that the component background size is somehow computed behind the scenes. So, even when I have the keyboard buttons and size how I want, the extraneous background covers some of my other control and it is very difficult to have a fine grained control over the size of the keyboard.

What is the right way to control the width and size of the virtual keyboard directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To Quote from the [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-virtualkeyboard-inputpanel.html#details)

> The keyboard size is automatically calculated from the available width; that is, the keyboard maintains the aspect ratio specified by the current style. Therefore the application should only set the width and y coordinates of the InputPanel, and not the height.

So if you want to have a specific height, you need to set the width accordingly.

> What is the right way to control the width and size of the virtual keyboard directly?

e.g.

```
InputPanel {
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.leftMargin: 100
    anchors.rightMargin: 100
}
```

e.g.

```
InputPanel {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    width: 30
}
```

So what's the deal with the `keyboardDesignHeight/Width`? Well this seems to be the dimensions of the keyboard, when it is not necessary to scale it:

> **scaleHint : real**
>   The keyboard style scale hint. This value is determined by dividing `keyboardHeight` by `keyboardDesignHeight`. All pixel dimensions must be proportional to this value.
>   *This property is readonly!*

So setting those will not disable the automatic resizing of your input panel in dependence of the width.

You might use them maybe, to calculate a ratio, and from this set the width to achieve your desired height.

Maybe this example helps you to understand this property:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id:appwindow
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Test")


    InputPanel {
        id: ip
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: 800

        Component.onCompleted: console.log(Object.keys(ip.keyboard.style).sort())
    }

    Slider {
        id: sl
        from: 0
        to: 3000
    }

    Binding {
        target: ip.keyboard.style
        property: 'keyboardDesignHeight'
        value: sl.value

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Makes a lot of sense. So, if you wanted a square keyboard, you would set them both to the same value.

Comment: So not clear how to calc width as `scaleHint = keyboardHeight / keyboardDesignHeight` - no width here. So how to convert desired height to width?

Comment: scaleHint * keyboardDesignWidth = width. scaleHint * keyboardDesignHeigth = height.

Comment: However `scaleHint` not set before we set keyboard `width` ;) If I know desirable height, correct width will be: `inputPanel.keyboard.style.keyboardDesignWidth / 
                   inputPanel.keyboard.style.keyboardDesignHeight *
                   (desired_height)`